# Is there a way to not render select dropdown values if it's disabled?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this chained plugin. http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

I am replicating this vehicle search box on tirerack.com on Shopify platform.

Here's my setup.

```js
<script>
  
  function submitAction(formObj) {
      var root  = formObj.action;
      var type  = formObj.elements['type'].value;
      var make  = formObj.elements['make'].value;
      var year  = formObj.elements['year'].value;
      var model = formObj.elements['model'].value.replace(/[\. ,:-]+/g, "-");

      var href = root + type + '/' + make + '+' + year + '+' + model;
      window.location.href = href;
      return false;
    }

</script>
<script>
  
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    /* For jquery.chained.js */
    $("#year").chained("#make");
    $("#model").chained("#year");

  });
</script>
```

```html
<form id="w-form" action="/collections/" method="get" onsubmit="return submitAction(this);">

    <select id="make" name="make" required>
      <option value="">Select Make</option>
      <option value="acura">Acura</option>
      <option value="alfa-romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
      <option value="american-motors">American Motors</option>
      <option value="aston-martin">Aston Martin</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    </select>
    <select id="year" name="year" required>
      <option value="">Select Year</option>
      <option value="2017 acura" class="acura">2017</option>
      <option value="2016 acura" class="acura">2016</option>
      <option value="2015 acura" class="acura">2015</option>
      <option value="2014 acura" class="acura">2014</option>

      <option value="1974 alfa-romeo" class="alfa-romeo">1974</option>
      <option value="1973 alfa-romeo" class="alfa-romeo">1973</option>
    </select>
    <select id="model" name="model" required>
      <option value="">Select Model</option>
      <option value="ILX"                   class="2016 acura">ILX</option>
      <option value="ILX A-SPEC Package"    class="2016 acura">ILX A-SPEC Package</option>
      <option value="MDX-FWD"               class="2016 acura">MDX FWD</option>
      <option value="MDX-SH-AWD"            class="2016 acura">MDX SH-AWD</option>
      <option value="RDX-AWD"               class="2016 acura">RDX AWD</option>
      <option value="RDX-FWD"               class="2016 acura">RDX FWD</option>
      <option value="RLX-FWD"               class="2016 acura">RLX FWD</option>
      <option value="RLX-SH-AWD"            class="2016 acura">RLX SH-AWD</option>
      <option value="TLX"                   class="2016 acura">TLX</option>

      <option value="GTV"                   class="1974 alfa-romeo">GTV</option>
      <option value="Spider"                class="1974 alfa-romeo">Spider</option>
      <option value="GTV"                   class="1973 alfa-romeo">GTV</option>
      <option value="Spider"                class="1973 alfa-romeo">Spider</option>
    </select>

    <select id="type" name="type" required>
      <option value="">I'm Shopping For</option>
      <option value="wheels">Wheels</option>
      <option value="tires">Tires</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="w-search-btn" value="View Results">
  </form>
```

Everything works so far.  The only issue is that the page loads slow on PC. On mobile and tablet, it's extremely slow. The reason it's loading slow is because I have 6000 records in the #model select dropdown(I'm only using few in the example above).

Why would it still be slow considering the #model select dropdown is disabled on page load and will only be abled once you select the make and year.  Also those 6000 records don't show up all at once.  Depending on what you select in the Make and Year, the relative records will show up in the #model dropdown.  So again, why is the page loading so slow? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the "Remote Version" they describe on http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained so that the initial page load isn't so heavy, and you hit your api to fetch records.  So, you'd need to create a few endpoints for the make/year/model/tires from which the script can fetch and point the plugin at them.

If you watch the network tab of developer tools while you use the controls on http://www.tirerack.com/, you'll see that this is what they do essentially, hitting their api each step in the process.

Comment: I tried their remote version setup and still don't notice any change in loading time.  Can you show me an example of what you're talking about creating endpoints for make/year/model?

Comment: You'd have to write server-side code to respond to the requests at the endpoints you tell the script to hit, eg if it hits ```http://yoursite/vehicleSearch.php?mark=bmw```, you'd respond with json like: ```{"":"--","series-1":"1 series","series-3":"3 series","series-5":"5 series","series-6":"6 series","series-7":"7 series"}```